# Desabilitar o link download enquanto o download está sendo feito

Tags: javascript, download

Como implementar essa funcionalidade?

Quando o usuário pressiona o link de Download ele vai receber uma mensagem de confirmação de download e onde quer guardar o arquivo.

Esse download demora em média uns 30s (pode chegar ate mais a depender da data requerida).

Eu queria desabilitar esse link durante o tempo que o download é feito e retornar ao normal quando o download é completado.

Existe algum evento para capturar o início e o fim do download?

### Update

A minha pergunta precisava de duas repostas para estar completa. @LeAndrade respondeu uma parte dela (como desabilitar o link `<a>`.
Eu vou postar aqui como fiz para capturar o fim do download.

1. No back-end (no meu caso php) crie uma função para enviar um cookie quando o arquivo fica disponível no Browser para o download. Note que não podemos saber se o usuário vai aceitar o download ou não. Aqui está o código `setcookie("statusDownloading", "done", time() + (300), "/");`
2. No front-end quando o usuário clica no link, este fica desabilitado (ou removido) e inicia um loop que fica procurando pelo cookie enviado pelo php, nesse caso `statusDownloading`. Quando o cookie é encontrado, o link é reestabelecido, o cookie é deletado e o loop é parado.

   ```
   function removeLink () {
       let htmlObj=$('#LinkDownload');

       htmlObj.detach();

       setTimeout(function(){
           let condition=true;
           while (condition) {
               let theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
               for (let i = 1 ; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
                   let str = theCookies[i-1];
                   let cookie=str.split("=");
                   let cookieName = cookie[0];
                   if(cookieName.trim() == 'statusDownloading'){

                       htmlObj.appendTo('#parentOfLinkDownload');

                       document.cookie = 'statusDownloading=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                       condition=false;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       }, 1000);
   }
   ```

Comment: acho que somente js nao consegue resolver o seu problema, provavelmente vc vai precisa criar um request token para ter resposta do client side.

Comment: Legal que conseguiu man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim isto é perfeitamente possível, repare no meu código de exemplo. Fiz uma função em **Javascript** que ao clicar no link `a`, o mesmo 'perde' o atributo `href` e após a contagem que no seu caso seria o download, ele volta a ter o href, mais explicações no código:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];  // pega a tag a

a.onclick = function() {                        // no clique do a
  a.attributes.removeNamedItem("href");         // removo o atributo href
  
  setTimeout(function() {                       // depois de 2 segundos
    var b = document.createAttribute("href");   // crio o atributo href de novo
    b.value = "#";                              // atribuo um link para ele
    a.setAttributeNode(b);                      // e seto o novo atributo no a
    console.log('Download concluído!');
  }, 2000);
  
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Clique aqui</a>
```

> Lembrando que não existe um método específico em javascript para capturar o início e o fim de um download!

Comment: sim. Postei como fiz para capturar o fim do processo. Valeu